# Mess with functions and associative arrays in ksh93

Tags: arrays, shell, ksh

This is my simple array:

```
typeset -A foo

foo["first"]="first Value"
foo["second"]="second Value"
```

And I want to do a function that would pick this array, do something and return it back to the script. e.g.

```
function changeThat {
    eval tmp=\$$1
    tmp["$2"]=$3
    return $tmp
}
```

I a way could go along in the script and do something like:

```
foo=changeThat foo "first" "a new first value"
```

And get a pretty result like

```
echo ${foo["first"]}
a new first value
```

Now this doesn't work... Well, I'm aware the syntax is prob not quite right. But I got really lost going through the nuances of `evals` and scape `echo` (not to say that I hate it from the bottom of my soul). Besides, my reference is for [bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html) and wouldn't be the first time I miss some trick when it comes to ksh - For instance, I've been so far in `ksh88`, which does't even have associative arrays, while most people say it should. Turns out that my AIX box does not agree. -_-

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your function like this:

```
function changeThat {
  typeset -n ref="$1"
  typeset key="$2"
  typeset value="$3"

  ref["$key"]="$value"
}
```

`typeset -n ref` defines the ref variable as a reference to the variable specified by it's value.

When you make this call to the function:

```
changeThat foo this "mow the lawn"
```

The variable ref in function changeThat references the variable foo.  Using ref is now just like using foo.  After calling changeThat

```
    print ${foo["this"]}
```

will now output "mow the lawn".